# How can I concatenate values in one cell based on a condition in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with values:

| ID | Type | Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | note | note by user1 |
| 2 | remark | remark by user |
| 3 | note | note by user2 |
| 4 | note | note by user 3 |
| 5 | remark | remark by adm |

How can I create another column where I could select concatenated values from 'Text' column. I need to select only Type column and concatenate values with a delimeter based on the type value. Table should look like this:

| Type | Text |
| --- | --- |
| note | note by user1; note by user2; note by user3 |
| remark | remark by user; remark by adm |

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use `listagg`

```
with x ( id, category, comments )as 
(
select 1 , 'note'   , 'note by user1'   from dual union all
select 2 , 'remark' , 'remark by user'  from dual union all
select 3 , 'note'   , 'note by user2'   from dual union all
select 4 , 'note'   , 'note by user 3'  from dual union all
select 5 , 'remark' , 'remark by adm'   from dual 
)
select category, listagg(comments,';' ) within group (order by id)
from x 
group by category ;
```

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=277fbb70c4becdb9101f0c09ac4991f0)

Comment: thank you. But what if I have hundreds unique types?

Comment: what about it ? you are grouping by it, so it will get only the distinct ones. No matter how many they are

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what if I have more columns and I can’t choose specific column to be grouped by?

Comment: @СаятОразов Then you need to work out what you can `GROUP BY` because if you (as a person) cannot determine how to logically organise the rows into groups then how will the SQL engine be able to perform that task?